# Upgrade Eclipse without opening it

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I have Eclipse Juno with Java EE, PHP, C++ and PyDev in it and it was working perfectly under Ubuntu 12.04 and later under 14.04.

Yet, when I upgraded my OS to Ubuntu 14.10, Eclipse doesn't work anymore, whenever I try to open it, it shuts down immediately.

I want to upgrade it to Luna but it doesn't give me the chance to launch the upgrade, I have an idea I have and wish to hear your advice on whether it is right or wrong.

What I'd like to do is to download Luna and extract it over the older version.

Will this work? Or will it make it even worse?

Is there anyone who tired it before?

Comment: Questions 1. What version of Ubuntu WERE you running i.e. 32/64 bit? 2. What version of eclipse WERE you running (32/64-bit). If you have been runing 64bit OS and 64-bit eclipse and upgraded to have a 32-bit OS (i know it's a stupid theory, but still it's diagnostically possible), but the eclipse remained to be a 64-bit version - chances are that you need to reinstall with 32-bit version.

Comment: @hagubear I have everything in 32bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may even download Luna, and extract it to a different folder (not necessary on top of the older version).

Afterwards, launch Luna and try to load your previous workspace(s). You might want to backup your workspaces folder, before letting Luna attempt and load from there.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the eclipse through the command line is safer. Try it using [eclipse site](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fupdate_standalone.html)

and also refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501164/2115983)

Answer (score 1):

I find solution here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=440660#c20 on comment 20

> This seems to be a bug in GTK according to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk2-engines-oxygen/+bug/1242801
>   (there a similar problem for Meld was reported).
>   Another workaround mentioned there is
>   For oxygen, edit the normally already existing file "/usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-2.0/gtkrc" and change
>       GtkComboBox::appears-as-list = 1
>   into
>       GtkComboBox::appears-as-list = 0

This workaround is working for me.